# Python How pause For loop and wait for form submission

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I have a list of items and I need to display these items on the web page through For loop(I use Flask and Jinja). But I only need items to be displayed one by one. For example: first element is shown, then user assign certain value using select form and press submit button, then next element shows up and so on..
So somehow I have to make the Loop wait for a user to submit the form. And only after that proceed to the next round.
Now I am only able to display all items at once but it's not what I need. As far as I know there are only two ways to pause loop: sleep() and input(), but none of them seem to fit. Does anybody have any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: i guess it will be easier to do that from the front side, then send all information to flask to run the back and give needed results.

Comment: You will need JS to accomplish this. When the user is *done* adding items to your list and presses *submit*, you post the data to your backend. Waiting form submission, sleeping etc. are **not** the things you should be looking for.

Comment: Yes, but user doesn't have to add items himself. All items are already preloaded in a list. User just needs to assign a certain value to it and submit.